# Scroll to specific div from another page minus X distance

Tags: javascript, animation, scroll

I'm using the following script to perform the action described in my title.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
              var jump=function(e)
      {
         if (e){
             e.preventDefault();
             var target = $(this).attr("href");
         }else{
             var target = location.hash;
         }

         $('html,body').animate(
         {
             scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
         },1000,function()
         {
             location.hash = target;
         });

      }

      $('html, body').hide();

      $(document).ready(function()
      {
          $('a[href^=#]').bind("click", jump);

          if (location.hash){
              setTimeout(function(){
                  $('html, body').scrollTop(0).show();
                  jump();
              }, 0);
          }else{
              $('html, body').show();
          }
      });
      </script>
```

It works perfectly fine. However I have a fixed header which covers up the div once it's scrolled to. I'd like to minus 80px from the desired scroll target. How can I modify the code to do this?

Here's a live version.

robertkoh.net/Electrotemp/index.html

Click on 'ducted vacuum systems'. It takes you to the products and services page and scrolls to the appropriate section. As you can see the fixed header covers part of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1: Subtract 80 pixels and do not re-set `location.hash`**

You only have to change this block:

```
 $('html,body').animate({
     scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
 }, 1000, function() {
     location.hash = target;
 });
```

Into the following code:

```
 $('html,body').animate({
     scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - 80
 }, 1000);
```

- The added `- 80` will subtract those 80 pixels, so the scrolling will stop earlier.
- Removing `location.hash = target;` (that was called after the scroll animation was finished) fixes the problem of jumping back to the old position. This code was re-setting the hash tag which caused the browser to scroll back again. But be aware that clicking site internal hash links would not update the hash in the URL bar any more.

**Solution 2: Move your page contents into a separate scrollable `<div>`**

- Create a new `<div id="container">` that starts after `<!--end slideMenu-->` and ends before `</body>`.
- Change the line `$('html,body').animate({` into `$('#container').animate({`.
- Remove `margin-top: 70px;` from `.titlebar`.
- Add this CSS for the `#container` element:

  ```
  #container {
      position: fixed;
      top: 70px;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      overflow: auto; /* enable scrolling */
  }
  ```

Doing it this way has some advantages:

- You do not have to add `- 80`.
- You do not have to remove `location.hash = target;`.
- A browser without JavaScript enabled jumps to the right position.

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work. It seems like it sort of does it, like it subtracts the 80 but then just jumps back to 0. I feel it has something to do with all the code below it resetting something?

Comment: It's difficult to guess without a live example. But you could try to remove the `.scrollTop(0)` part from this line: `$('html, body').scrollTop(0).show();`.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I tried that too but still no success. Here's a live version.

http://www.robertkoh.net/Electrotemp/index.html

Click on 'ducted vacuum systems'. It takes you to the products and services page and scrolls to the appropriate section. As you can see the fixed header covers part of it.

Comment: The example link http://www.robertkoh.net/Electrotemp/prodserv.html#vacuum works for me in Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Internet Explorer. Does this link work in your browser?

Comment: Umm, the example I uploaded does not include your suggestions of how to edit the JS to scroll to target minus 80px. It's just using the code I pasted in the question. Are you saying you got this working somehow to scroll to the target minus 80? If you look in my example it scrolls exactly to the top, where the fixed header nav covers part of the div i'm trying to show.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that `jumps back to 0` means that the browser jumps to the top of the page, not only those 80 pixels. I updated my answer - now it should really work ;).